# Prevent jQuery Mobile radio buttons from stacking on top one another when screen is reduced.

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have a set of jQuery Mobile radio buttons with data-type="horizontal and data-mini="true" in the fieldset.
Obviously I'm using this on a mobile site but when the screen size is reduced the radio buttons  become stacked on top one another.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/sg8EJ/3/

```
       <fieldset  class="changeFulfilment" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
               <input class="changeFulfillmentInput" type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-1"/>
               <label for="radio-mini-1">long Button----------</label>

               <input class="changeFulfillmentInput"  type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-2" />
               <label for="radio-mini-2">short</label>
       </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give its container div a min-width with css. This will solve your problem.